# Can a nonzero matrix be PSD and have zero trace?

Tags: matrices, examples-counterexamples, trace, positive-semidefinite

Does there exist an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ which satisfies the following?

1. $A \succeq 0$ ($A$ is positive semidefinite)
2. $\sum_i A_{ii} = 0$ (trace of $A$ is zero)
3. $A \neq 0$ ($A$ is not the zero matrix)

I know that there exist no such matrices which are symmetric, but I am not sure how to prove that no matrices satisfy the above for the case of non-symmetric matrices, or to otherwise find a counterexample.

Comment: PSD (and its cousins PD, NSD and ND) is usually a term reserved for symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay actually I asked this question way too hastily...

$A =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$
is positive semidefinite, nonzero, and has zero trace.

Comment: PSD'ness of non-symmetric matrices is a delicate topic.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am not sure what you mean to point out by "your question uses $\exists$, not $\forall$." Also for PSD'ness of a non-symmetric matrix, I am simply using the definition $x^T A x \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If you like, Mathematica's `PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ` returns `True` for this matrix; I think they use this definition.

Comment: You are correct. I misread.

Comment: In any case, the crux of the matter is that the skew-symmetric part of matrix $A$ contributes zero to the quadratic form. Only the symmetric part contributes. Hence, $A$ is replaced by its symmetric part in the quadratic form, i.e., $$x^\top \left( \frac{A + A^\top}{2} \right) x$$ Do note that the symmetric part of your matrix $A$ is the **zero** matrix, which is technically PSD.